# array_diff траблы

Tags: php

Имею следующий код:

```
$base = "111111,222222,333333";
$xml = "
 <item>
    <id>111111</id>
    <status>cancel</status>
    <status_ext>test_order</status_ext>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>222222</id>
    <status>cancel</status>
    <status_ext>test_order</status_ext>
  </item>
 ";

$base_arr = explode(',', $base);
preg_match_all('#<id>(.*?)</id>#', $xml, $xml_arr);

$result_not_xml = array_diff($base_arr, $xml_arr[0]);

print_r($base_arr);
print_r($xml_arr[0]);
print_r ($result_not_xml);
```

Получаю вывод - будто ни один из элементов `$base_arr` не содержится в `$xml_arr[0]`:

Array ( [0] => 111111 [1] => 222222 [2] => 333333 )

Array ( [0] => 111111 [1] => 222222 )

Array ( [0] => 111111 [1] => 222222 [2] => 333333 )

Так и не понял как пофиксить...

Comment: [вот ответ на ваш вопрос ](http://ideone.com/lUPTSz#view_edit_box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в строке:

```
$result_not_xml = array_diff($base_arr, $xml_arr[0]);
```

Нужно изменить на:

```
$result_not_xml = array_diff($base_arr, $xml_arr[1]);
```

Так как нулевой индекс содержит строку полного вхождения. То есть вместе с тегами <id>...</id>. 
Возможно вы смотрели вывод в режиме html, в котором теги превратились в теги.